# Infopath form add custom button

Tags: 2010, javascript, infopath

I have a SharePoint 2010 list and I customize the form using InfoPath, now I add a content web part to edit form to display a custom button in the form ribbon like in this form from another list [image]

but using the same code the icon don't appear

[image]

here the code that I'm using:

```
<script src="/Documents/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/Documents/jQuery/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <style type="text/css" media="print">
   @page  {size: auto; }</style>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('​<img width="77" height="79" id="PrimeiraAdenda" title="Print" alt="Print.png" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm" src="link to image"  style=" cursor:hand; margin: 5px; width: 52px; height: 52px;"/>').insertAfter   ($('[role=tabpanel] li').last());


 $('#PrintAdenda').click(function(){
   stuff
  })

 });


</script>​ ​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Do you wish to add a submit button on your custom InfoPath form?

Comment: No, the rest of the code I hide. that button (The printer), uses SPServices to generate a pdf template from the selected item

Answer (score 1):

No need for code, just use SharePoint Designer to add a Custom Action:

- connect to the site using SharePoint Designer
- go to 'Lists and Libraries' and open the list by clicking on the name
- go to 'Custom Action' in the ribbon and choose 'View Ribbon'
- type a name
- choose 'Navigate to URL' and fill in the correct URL to the page (use {selecteditemid} in the query string for the id of the selected item
- specify the images

Comment: I can´t use SharePoint designer :(

Comment: you can also use Javascript to add a custom action button to the Ribbon, see the following question on StackOverflow: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101982/add-ribbon-button-via-javascript

Comment: If you edit the form with infopath you won't be able to add custom actions... I have just lost three buttons.  :((