# Add a custom action button to a specific group in ribbon using JavaScript?

Tags: 2010, javascript, custom-list, ribbon, custom-actions

I would like to add a custom action in the group "Connect and export" of the list ribbon when on the AllItems.aspx page.
No server code is allowed. This should be done by using JavaScript. The picture shows where the new custom button should be added.

[image]

By now, I succeed to add the button to another group. Unfortunetely it is added every time I refresh the page. You can find the source [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101982/add-ribbon-button-via-javascript).

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(AddExportXlsCustomButton,"sp.js");
});

function AddExportXlsCustomButton(){
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Dossiers CRME");
    var customAction = list.get_userCustomActions().add();
    customAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView');
    var uiExtension = '<CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">' +
                    '<CommandUIDefinitions>' +
                        '<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.CustomizeList.Controls._children">'+
                            '<Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.RibbonCustomExcelExport" '+
                                    'Command="Notify" '+
                                    'Sequence="0" '+
                                    'Image16by16="/_layouts/1036/images/formatmap16x16.png" '+
                                    'Image32by32="/_layouts/1036/images/formatmap32x32.png" '+
                                    'Description="Exporte les éléments sélectionnés vers un fichier Excel." '+
                                    'LabelText="Exporter vers Excel (Personnalisé)" '+
                                    'TemplateAlias="o1"/>' +
                        '</CommandUIDefinition>'+
                    '</CommandUIDefinitions>'+
                    '<CommandUIHandlers>'+
                        '<CommandUIHandler Command="Notify" '+
                            'CommandAction="javascript: ;" />'+
                    '</CommandUIHandlers>'+
                   '</CommandUIExtension>';
    customAction.set_commandUIExtension(uiExtension);
    customAction.update();
    context.load(list,'UserCustomActions');
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, success),Function.createDelegate(this, error));
}   

function success(){ console.log("success"); }

function error(){ alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You might also want to check this library I created: https://github.com/Aymkdn/RibbonPlus/

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
'<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.CustomizeList.Controls._children">'+
```

Should be

```
'<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.Actions.Controls._children">'+
```

Those links helps me out:

http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2013/09/add-ribbon-button-in-connect-export.html 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543(v=office.14).aspx.