# To add a link button((Custom action)) in SharePoint 2013 document library page's Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, document-library, custom-action, site-level-ribbon

How to add a link(Custom action) to a document library page's Ribbon with java script. And where to add that java-script? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Ribbon Button using JavaScript API. You need to add the script in Content Editor or Script Editor Web Part

```
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.site = context.get_web();
var customAction = this.site.get_userCustomActions().add();
customAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon.NewForm');

var uiExtension = '<CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">' +
                        '<CommandUIDefinitions>' +
                            '<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Commit.Controls._children">'+
                                '<Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.RibbonTest" '+
                                        'Command="PrintPage" '+
                                        'Sequence="0" '+
                                        'Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_16x16.png" '+
                                        'Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_32x32.png" '+
                                        'Description="Uses the notification area to display a message." '+
                                        'LabelText="Notify hello" '+
                                        'TemplateAlias="o1"/>' +
                            '</CommandUIDefinition>'+
                        '</CommandUIDefinitions>'+
                        '<CommandUIHandlers>'+
                            '<CommandUIHandler Command="PrintPage" '+
                                'CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(\'Hello from the notification area\');" />'+
                        '</CommandUIHandlers>'+
                       '</CommandUIExtension>';

customAction.set_commandUIExtension(uiExtension);

customAction.set_registrationId("0x0108");
customAction.set_registrationType(SP.UserCustomActionRegistrationType.contentType);

customAction.update();

context.load(this.site,'UserCustomActions');

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailure));
```

[SP.UserCustomActionCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408647(v=office.14).aspx)

Please refer the
[Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101982/add-ribbon-button-via-javascript)

Or else simply you can use SharePoint Designer to add the 
[Custom Ribbon Action using SPD2013](https://www.abelsolutions.com/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/)

Comment: i am trying to add this code in content editor in a document library page. But after adding the code, even the ribbon stops appearing in the page. Same is with script editor web part.